# Using JSON to loop data in the view of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am a pretty new to asp.net mvc with JSON. Now I want to get the data from the list, that I query it in my controller. Using the JSON to loop all that data to view in my views.
Any idea of doing it? Because I never try it before. 
Thanks for all your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [this](http://mazharkaunain.blogspot.com/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-using-jsonresult.html) is what you are looking for

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.